# Is there a General Binding Rule to resolve severals : Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class

Tags: java, binding, xsd, jaxb, wsdl

I'm working to generate java class from a WSDL and several XSD files.  One of the XSD contain more than 1000 complexType/element that causing the error:

Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class

I found how to fix each of them by using a binding rule like:

```
<jxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='ProjectEmployeeExpenseLineKey']">
     <jxb:factoryMethod name="ProjectEmployeeExpenseLineKeyEl"/>
</jxb:bindings>
```

But since there is so many to fix I'm searching for a genera rule to fix them all.

I found something about prefix but haven`t succeed in making it works.  It look like this:

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="Microsoft1.xsd" >
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:nameXmlTransform>
                <jxb:elementName suffix="Element"/>
            </jxb:nameXmlTransform>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong..

If you can help me to figure it out... Your wisdom and valuable knowledge is welcome :-)

Thanks
David

Comment: Did you find a solution to this David? I'm struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Any solutions yet...?